# If I have my own oauth account on Twitter_ Token, know_ Device_ Token, how do I get oauth_ Token_ Secret

Tags: oauth, token

I broke out of prison on IOS on my iPhone and found com. atebits. Tweetie2. plist, but I couldn't find oauth_ Token_ Secret

I want to reply to my friends on my automation software and post some interesting things, so I need the oauth of my account_ Token_ Secret, I don't want to use the developer's oauth_ Token_ Secret